# How to give a website (Wordpress) a custom title and description in Google search

Tags: google-search, seo

it's about the website www.kindheitsorte.de.

When you do a Google search for "kindheitsorte.de" you get to see "kindheitsorte.de/" as the result - no custom site title or description at all. When you do a Google search for "kindheitsorte" you get "Informationen" as the site title (which is pretty weird because this title has never been added - you can't even see it in the website's source code.

The website is running on Wordpress 2.9.2 and makes use of the All in One SEO Pack 1.6.13. I have added a custom description for each page with the All in One SEO Pack since the Home page of the website does not contain any text that Goolge could be interested in.

What do I have to do in order to have Google display the right title and also the description I have added?

Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 2):

The problem had a very simple cause - the WP privacy settings were set to "hide blog" without me noticing, that's why the website did not get craweled well by Google.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that Google favors English webpage Titles. Try changing your title from

```
<title>Buchpräsentation | Kindheitsorte - Eine Zieglerkindheit an der Havel</title>
```

to
    Childhood places

Also, consider serving the visitor their language with [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/).

Comment: This can't be the reason since the same problem occurs when using Google.de which should (and obviously doesn't) favor English language page titles. The website is serving a domestic audience only (it belongs to a book which is only available in German), so using the qtranslate plugin would not make much sense in this case. But thank you anyway!